# What mathematical property is fulfilled by $\mathbb{S}_2$ but not $\mathbb{S}_1$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

Let $\Bbb{S}_1=\lbrace1,2,3,4\rbrace$ and let $\Bbb{S}_2=\lbrace1,12,34,41\rbrace$.

Intuitively, I can see that the elements of $\Bbb{S}_2$ are 'further' from each other than the elements of $\Bbb{S}_1$, and that the range of $\Bbb{S}_2$ is much larger.

Is there a one-word mathematical property which is fulfilled by $\mathbb{S}_2$ but not by 
$\mathbb{S}_1$?

**Note:** This question is adapted from [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/245800/is-there-a-term-that-means-that-the-numbers-are-well-spread-out) unanswered question on English Language Learners Stack Exchange, I thought it might be better received here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $\mathbb S_2$ has more [dispersion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_dispersion) than $\mathbb S_1$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Does this only apply to probability distributions, or can any set be more dispersed than another set? I don't know much about statistics.

Comment: This question seems rather odd and unmotivated.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 See the note for motivation.

Comment: $\mathbb{S}_2$ has greater variance from its average than $\mathbb{S}_1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In English, "range" is a good answer.  It reflects how far apart the extremes are.  My second choice would be "notnexttoeachother", pretending it is adopted from German.

Comment: Mein face ven ze Germänn teechär makes me spell "Rindfleischetikettierungsüberwachungsaufgabenübertragungsgesetz": :(

Comment: Maybe "inconsecutive" could be considered English.